# PHP Replace and Remove?

Tags: php, replace, string

I have random Product Links URL.

I want the result Like  >

http://yourdomain.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=5
Product Id = 5
or 
http://yourdomain.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=3210:cdfa96a858cdde666a79b09207528297
Product Id = 3210

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please explain yourself better

Comment: The first place to start working on this is actually asking a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "http://yourdomain.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=5";
$pattern = "/products_id=(\d+)/";
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
$out = "Product Id = ".$matches[1];
```